# Could you create a website font-end using Python Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, browser

I have a question. Would it be possible to create web apps using Python Tkinter for front end? The reason, that to create a website you need to know a lot of things. Such as HTML/CSS/JS. Would it be possible create browser based apps using python only?

Answer (score 3):

Not possible. Tkinter is a desktop UI development framework.

You can use any web framework like Django, Flask and many more to create web apps. Or you can use any front-end framework like Angular, Vue, React and many more and then create an API to make requests to a Python-based server.

Answer (score 2):

No, tkinter cannot run in a web browser, only on the desktop.

You might be interested in [PyScript](https://pyscript.net/) if you wish to run Python applications in a web browser.